# Geometric way of seeing the following inequality.

Tags: real-analysis

I am dealing with a Real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ in the following inequality so triangle inequality is satisfied. Suppose that we know there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|b - b_n| < \frac{|b|}{2}$ whenever $n \geq N_1$.
I want to know why geometrically $|b_n| > \frac{|b|}{2}$ ?
I can see it algebraically. The reason being $|b| = |b + b_n - b_n| \leq |b - b_n| + |b_n| < \frac{|b|}{2} + |b_n|$.

From the inequality above we get $|b_n| > \frac{|b|}{2}$.
I would like to build the mental picture of why this is true, so I could use my intuition for harder problems. If someone could explain in detail that would be appreciated.

Comment: In a general metric space, you might not be able to add or subtract points so $|b-b_n|$ may not make sense. Do you mean a normed vector space? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space

Comment: Let us say where I replace the $|b - b_n|$ with $d(b,b_n)$.

Comment: If your metric space is a normed vector space then would also have to have $|b|=d(b,0)$ as well. But then you are assuming that the metric space has some kind of special point $0$. Then you are making a assumptions about the space which aren't true of all spaces, so you will have a distorted view of what metric spaces are which won't help your intuition.

Comment: Alright, I will just add extra condition that it is a normed vector space. I just want to see it for R, but of course generalizing it for other spaces means is good. I have edited my question, but feel free to add your edits as well in order to capture as much generalized version as possible. I just want to have a picture in my head instead of relying on algebra alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it obvious geometrically?  If $P$ is a point in space, of distance $\lambda$ from the origin, and $Q$ is a point whose distance from $P$ is $< \frac{\lambda}{2}$, then $Q$ lies inside the sphere with center $P$ and radius $\frac{\lambda}{2}$.  Every point inside that sphere is clearly of distance more than $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ from the origin.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by Q is a point whose distance from Q < $\frac{\lambda}{2}$?

Comment: Could you please clarify this issue ?

Comment: Done ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Why is every point inside the sphere distance of $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ from the origin ?

Comment: It'll probably be more clear to you if you draw a picture/visualize it in your head than if I explain it.

Comment: I mean, I could give you a proof, but it would be exactly the proof you gave above.

Comment: Yes I understand sorry for my late reply! I was away for 2 days.

Comment: No problem, you're not on the clock or anything.